# Did I do something wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question, etiquette, accepted-answer

I recently put up a question about how each byte in the PMD-85's video RAM is used.

I got two answers, which while informative, didn't quite give me exactly what I wanted. Raffzahn's in particular was informative and showed me exactly what gave rise to the bizarre resolution and memory layout of that machine.

And then a post from Radovan confirmed my speculations, and also had a link in it to a page which had the information I was after. I invited him to work the information from that link into his answer, but that didn't happen.

So now I wrote an answer myself and accepted it. I've had some sour feedback about it and it seems one of the other answerers resented that. I absolutely don't want any problems here.

Did I do something wrong?

If I did, it is possible to have it reverted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is an official answer (at least, as much as I can make it) because having an opinion is hard and I'm lazy.

---

### Technically, no.

- You wrote an answer that took from multiple sources, and provided attribution. [This is allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60458/308065).
- You accepted an answer of your choosing. That's your right; [not even moderators have the authority to change it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120569/308065).

Whether it was a good idea or not I'll leave to people with an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> I've had some sour feedback about it and it seems one of the other answerers resented that.

For one, as [it was me](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7331/how-does-the-pmd-85-display-colour-or-greyscales#comment20733_7343), I would prefer to be called by name, not some vague wording. Especially if it's quite clear whom you're talking about (*1). Equaly important, unlike you seam to belive, my remark wasn't in any way related to me writing an answer as well. I may have added the same remark without having writen an answer prior.

> I absolutely don't want any problems here.

I wouldn't call it a problem, but a hint to think about.

> Did I do something wrong?

As Wizzzwizz4 already pointed out, technicaly no (*2). It goes as with everything else in life, what's not explicit forbidden (like due software) is allowed.

The question is rather *was it the right thing to do*?

As so often in life it's twofold (*3) and relates to content and presentation.

- There was already [an answer that clearly points out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7332/6659) the basics in a compact manner and pointing to a webpage describing the whole issue in great detail. While plea guilty on *always* writing way too lengthy answers about simple issues, I do try to not copy much from other sources. That's what links are for.
- Answering one owns question is already a not realy considered good behaviour. After all, questions are made to receive answers from others, aren't they? Sure there might be situations, when one discovers the result independant - and noone else did come up with a fiting reply (*4). Some thing that isn't true here.

  Related is the case of accepting. Accepting one owns question as 'the right one' laready leaves a bad taste. Even more so if the content made up from retriving the information of another question and rewrite it into a new and **without** realy extending it.

  Accepting is a powerful statment about an answer and always should be applied with care.

  (On a side note, but related, accepting answers in Meta is even more delicate, as it's usually not about simple technical issues - even more, in meta roles are usually switched, as it's about collecting opinions. Beside that there is no real way of picking 'the' answer at all, accepting one does give it an authorative glow as if that's something agreed upon - which it isn't. it's just the OP selectig the one he linked best, no matter how many agreed or disagreed. So when it comes to Meta, seeing a question with an accepted answer is like a huge warning sign about its content.).

> If I did, it is possible to have it reverted?

I can't tell, I assume it needs an edit of the answer, or adding a new one to make the software allows to change your decison. And even then I'm not sure it can be purely revoked, without atributing it to someone else.

But what *could have* been done for example was you editing [Radovan](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/476/radovan-garab%C3%ADk)'s answer by incooperating the tables from the link. He always has a chance to revert your changes, but I can well imagine he would have apreciate your work as much as I would.

If writing another answer with the same content is belived to be neccessary, accepting the original - or at least non accepting either would have been a respectful way.

Also, accepting an answer should not be done in a hurry - leting a week pass and then rewiew what did come up might be a good way to get a wider picture and founded decision. Especially since this is RC with it's rather limited audience, at least compared to the main site (*5).

Bottom line: I would love if this could lead to a more respectful action toward the one offering the information in the first place. People spend a considerable amount of time researching information the questioneer wants. They have no interest here beside helping. It's a gift, not a (payed) service.

---

*1 - I'm aware that this is the net and therefore there's a need to take things said safe, but were I'm from, such a combination may be considered a personal attack.

*2 - One remark here: Opinion is always an automatic result of known information - not having  one isn't possible.

*3 - While easy on opinion, I always have a hard time to cut down number of valid issues, as I feel it it's a bad idea to focus too hard.

*4 - Another case could be that the answer was conceived during discusion to the question. Here a self writen answer might be a great way to consolidate this into a coherent answer posting.

*5 - Not saying RC is small, no way. I'm amazed what comes up on RC. I considere myself not totally uninformed about computers, and there are many things over the last year that if not totaly new, at least made me researching details and learning about many new nuances. Still, it's an issue of scale, isn't it :))

Comment: Is this why you don’t accept your own answers, *e.g.* [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9673/79) or [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/13290/79)? Quite a few of your self-answers are definitely worthy of acceptance IMO...

Comment: @StephenKitt Naa - there's a secret plan of world domination. I will write lie 2-3 such Q&A a year, and one day, in 100 years, I will accept them all at once, breaking SE's accounting system Muhahaha .... But serious, It simply feels wrong to me to award myself with these points, or put my research over others. True, the examples you cite didn't get any other answer, but this as well means there is no gain in selecting my own. So yeah, I guess I'm the odd guy here.